# Get distance from focused object in opencv

Tags: xcode, opencv

I have detected the circles using the OpenCV Framework . Now I would like to calculate the distance from the detected circle . Please tell me how to do this. Any Ideas would be grateful. Thanks in advance . Please Let me know if my question is not clear .

Comment: Do you know the original size in cm of the circle that you detected on the image? If so it is just simple intercept theorem. It not you need some other kind of reference.

Comment: I don't know the Original side of the circle Dobi . Please give me some suggestion or ideas. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an image of a circle: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/Toghrol_Tower_looking_up.jpg Now please tell me its distance. Do you know what I mean? :-)